# Bitrix где изменить мета-тег Last-Modified?

Tags: битрикс, шаблоны

Здравствуйте! Работаю с сайтом, у которого мета-тег Last-Modified имеет значение 2014 года. Надо изменить перед тем, как запрашивать переиндексацию.

Подскажите, где это можно сделать? Какая папка, какой файл?
Сейчас можно эту дату на весь сайт. То есть в шаблон.

Проблема в том, что с битрикс начала работать недавно. Плохо представляю, что и где находится в админке. Или в структуре папок, если непосредственно в файлах по ftp скачивать и изменять.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла, как в шаблоне поменять дату:

Администрирование → Настройки → Настройки продукта → Сайты → Шаблоны сайтов. Выбираем сайт. В правой части - вкладка Шаблон. Прокручиваем вниз, там код, где меняем дату